# Refreshing Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view rendered with an `Html.Action()` that I want to refresh on a button click. I've tried AJAX requests, but the data I'm passing back and forth exceeds the maximum length for JSON.

The basic structure of the page looks like:

```
<html>
   <head>
   ...
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         @Html.Action("DisplayBox")
      </div>
      <div>
         <input type="button" id="RefreshButton" value="Refresh Box" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The reason why I'm asking for a method other than an AJAX request is that the partial I'm rendering is a PDF object:

```
@model byte[]
@{
   String base64EncodedPDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model);
   Layout = null;
}

<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@base64EncodedPDF" 
   width="900" height="900" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

Thus, the data passed to the partial view for rendering is too big to put in an AJAX request. On button click, I want to be able to execute the controller action and have the results update the partial with new data. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: In your example, there is no data, so it's complicated to find solution, give us data :-)

Comment: Save the PDF to a file on the server under the document root and then include it via URL instead of passing the data directly to the `object` tag. Then, for refresh, you can simply update the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the HTML with the link to the controller that generate the PDF or generate the file on the server side, host it and return the URL of this PDF, then, javascript can redirect user to that file.

I don't think that returning file trough AJAX is really not a good practice!